android:path deeplink opens in web browser rather than redirecting to app
I've react-native android app in which my android:path ='/reader/all' deeplink is not working. Here the path is opening on browser instead of redirecting to app. However android:pathPrefix="/reader/settings/digest" works as expected.
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml.
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.xyz.com" android:path="/reader/all"/>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.xyz.com" android:pathPrefix="/reader/settings/digest"/>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.xyz.com" android:pathPrefix="/reader/fo"/>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.xyz.com" android:pathPrefix="/reader/fe"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>


when u click on deep link, the path is 'www.xyz.com/reader/all' right? since android:path should be exact match for the URL path

yes that is correct.. i've tried adding the full url in path even that doesn't work.

I'm trying to use android:path as you but I can open deep link

and your config exactly like me
